# Easy jQuery question, nested selectors and parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to hover an image and popup a div, without plugins. just basic jquery
the jQuery is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".wrapperfortooltip div img").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css('border', 'solid 1px #E90E65');
            $("div", this).stop().fadeIn();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid #3E3D3D');
            $("div",this).stop().fadeOut();
        }
    );
});
</script>
```

The HTML is like this:

```
<div class="wrapperfortooltip">
    <div style="position:relative;">
        <img src="images/question.gif" alt="Tooltip" style="border: 1px solid #3E3D3D;" />
        <div class="tooltipVzw" style="position: absolute; display: none; width: 215px; top: 0px; left: -235px; ">
            Message to display nr one
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative;">
        <img src="images/question.gif" alt="Tooltip" style="border: 1px solid #3E3D3D;" />
        <div class="tooltipVzw" style="position: absolute; display: none; width: 215px; top: 0px; left: -235px; ">
            Message to display
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS(for whom might be interested)

```
.tooltipVzw
{
    border: solid 1px #3e3d3d;
    color: #cfc6ca;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 9px 9px 9px 9px;
    background-image: url(images/tooltipvzwbg.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-color:#1c1c1c;
    text-align:left;
    line-height: 16px;
}
```

Now I have to find a way to do modify

```
$("div", this).stop().fadeIn();
```

to something like this:

```
$(this).parent().("div").stop().fadeIn();
```

So my actual question is: How do I fix the line above so that it works. or am I completely wrong?

Comment: See the answers others gave below. Just so you understand, the last line of code you gave is almost there. You're just missing a function name like `$(this).parent().find("div").stop().fadeIn();` Nevertheless, the answers given will be more efficient.

Comment: thanks patrick for your answer. now i learned both approaches!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `div` seems to be always the element after the `img` you can just use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$(this).next().stop().fadeIn();
```

or with a filter to be on the safe side:

```
$(this).next('.tooltipVzw').stop().fadeIn();
```

Comment: +1 for the appropriate class selector. `.siblings('.tooltipVzw')` could also be used if the relative position of the tooltip is uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 $(this).next().stop().fadeIn();
```

This finds the next sibling and displays it.  It's strongly dependent on the DOM structure.  A more general solution might be to use `$(this).nextAll('div')...` or `$(this).parent().find('div')...`.